# expressjs socket.io port 3000 is already in use

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Should I need to to specify different ports for express (3000) and socket.io?

Error: port 3000 is already in use

my code:

index.js

```
var express = require('express')
,router = express.Router()
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.Server(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(3000);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    console.log("A user is connected");

    socket.on('point1', function (value) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('point1',value);
    });

    socket.on('less1', function (value) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('less1',value);
    });

    socket.on('point2', function (value) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('point2',value);
    });

    socket.on('less2', function (value) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('less2',value);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();
</script>
```

or how can I pass a variable on the io.connect("use-host:use-port");

on the index.html from app.js or a config file.

Comment: change your port form 3000 to some other port eg:3002

Comment: use like this  `server.listen(process.env.PORT);`

Comment: on my index.html, how do I supply a variable to <script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();
</script> so I dont keep on changing the port and the host?